# Backbone multiple event handlers issue: only one method called for the same event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js

I have backbone js app that has a view and many subviews.

My code looks like:

```
var BooksView = Backbone.View.extend({

   events: {
      "submit #book_form": "createBook"
   },

   render: function() {
      var bookSocialView = new BookSocialView({
          el: $('#the_books_social_div')
      });
      bookSocialView.render();
   },

   createBook: function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      ...
   }

});
```

and my bookSocialView looks like:

```
var BookSocialView = Backbone.View.extend({
   events: {
      "blur .socialInput": "getSocial",
      "submit #book_form": "getSocial"
   },
   render: function () {
    ...
   },
   getSocial: function (e) {
       ...
   }
});
```

Right now, my blur .socialInput calls getSocial, but my submit #book_form doesn't. There aren't any errors in the console, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have an event handler for `submit` in `BooksView`, it is probably what gets called first. But inside the handler you call `e.preventDefault()` and it prevents the submit event from reaching `BookSocialView.getSocial()`

It is better to rethink your strategy around book_form submit logic. If you want multiple handlers to work, but also want to prevent form sumbission, I would suggest using [custom events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events). You handler can still do `e.preventDefault()` but should also trigger additional event like `myModel.trigger('refreshSocial')`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if there is a way to call blur automatically, so when the form is submit, it automatically loses focus?

Comment: To loose focus it needs to move somewhere. Just find something else that needs focus and call `$el.focus()`

Comment: Ok, thanks. Another question: Doesn't blur trigger on end of focus? Why would I be able to click the submit button without blur triggering on a form element?

Comment: Submit button is typically inside the form. Blur is called when focus is moved outside of the element. When you click on submit, technically focus remains within the form. On a side note, I find blur events useless in most cases as there are better ways to achieve the same functionality.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Is there an event I could use to achieve basically the same thing as Blur, but so it loses focus when the submit button's clicked?

Comment: See my first commment here. Normally, logic of your web site should tell you where to move focus upon form submit. Easy to test would be to use the search field in the hav bar (if you have one). Just focus on it after submit has been clicked. More useful is to focus somewhere on the first element of what user is most likely to do next. If the form submit opens another view, focus on the first element inside it. You can only focus on something clickable, though (text edits, buttons, links...).

Comment: Doesn't focusing on something else seem a little hacky? Is there no clean solution to just take the focus off the field on button submit? Btw, thanks for all your help!

Comment: You can also do `$(window).focus()` to achieve what you want. I suggest you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_(computing). Concept of the focus is, it cannot disappear. SOMETHING is always in focus. Please, mark the answer if it helped. Ask a new question for a different problem. Comments are here for a different purpose. Cheers!